How to use Laravel's Policy to authorize actions based on a specific attribute of a related model?
I have a Laravel application with two models: Post and User. Each Post belongs to a User, and I want to authorize actions on a Post based on a specific attribute of the User who owns the post.
For instance, I only want users who have the is_admin attribute set to true to be able to delete posts, regardless of who created the post.
Here's my current setup:
User Models
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'is_admin',
    ];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}

Post Model
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'content', 'user_id',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

The Policy
namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Post;

class PostPolicy
{
    public function delete(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        // Checking if the user is admin
        return $user->is_admin;
    }
}


Registered the policy in AuthServiceProvider
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Policies\PostPolicy;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        Post::class => PostPolicy::class,
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}

The Post Controller
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        $this->authorize('delete', $post);

        $post->delete();

        return redirect()->route('posts.index')->with('success', 'Post deleted successfully.');
    }
}

Is this the correct way to use a policy to authorize actions based on a related model's attribute?
Are there any best practices or improvements I can make to this setup?
